# HTTP ERROR 500 - domain is unable to handle this request

Tags: yii2

I am running my application on my local using Laragon. Upon running my app, it says `HTTP ERROR 500 - domain is unable to handle this request`. Now, this error is too generic so I've checked my apache error log file but there is nothing substantial with the message:

```
[Wed Dec 29 11:09:19.659652 2021] [core:warn] [pid 15608:tid 640] AH00098: pid file C:/laragon/bin/apache/httpd-2.4.47-win64-VS16/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Dec 29 11:09:19.662662 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15608:tid 640] AH00455: Apache/2.4.47 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1k mod_fcgid/2.3.10-dev configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Dec 29 11:09:19.662662 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15608:tid 640] AH00456: Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: Apr 24 2021 11:08:47
[Wed Dec 29 11:09:19.662662 2021] [core:notice] [pid 15608:tid 640] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\laragon\\bin\\apache\\httpd-2.4.47-win64-VS16\\bin\\httpd -d C:/laragon/bin/apache/httpd-2.4.47-win64-VS16'
[Wed Dec 29 11:09:19.664662 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15608:tid 640] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 11520
[Wed Dec 29 11:09:20.146271 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11520:tid 572] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

On my `ht.access`:

```
Options -Indexes

# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git|.key)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  !=on 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

I've looked through many solutions here but it does not solve my problem. I found a workaround that is to add `error_reporting(0)` to my `index.php` that solves this problem and the app will run normally although I don't think this is an ideal solution.

Is there any possible way I could dig more to find the cause of this issue other than turning off the error reporting?

Comment: Try checking `runtime/logs` folder for more info about the error. The apache log you've posted doesn't contain any info about error it's just info about apache start.

Comment: Upon checking it, I see this message `2021-12-31 09:51:59 [127.0.0.1][3][-][warning][yii\log\Dispatcher::dispatch] Unable to send log via codemix\streamlog\Target: Exception (Log Runtime) 'yii\log\LogRuntimeException' with message 'Unable to export log!: fwrite(): Write of 778 bytes failed with errno=9 Bad file descriptor' ` , not sure if it's related to my issue.